# How do I Extract multiple values from same form select item using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms

Hi I have the following basic form with a select option value element.  when a user selects an item in the form, I'd like to use jquery to extract the values associated with this selection.  I have stored the required values in the form, but I don't know how to extract the elements I need from the array.  I'm a jquery novice so all help is welcomed.  Here's my code:

```js
$("select[player=name1]").on('change', function() {
  $('#Player_1').html($(this).find('option:selected').text());
  playerarray1 = $('option:selected').val();
  alert(playerarray1);
});

$("select[player=name2]").on('change', function() {
  $('#Player_2').html($(this).find('option:selected').text());
  playerarray2 = $('option:selected').val();
  alert(playerarray2);
});

$("select[player=name3]").on('change', function() {
  $('#Player_3').html($(this).find('option:selected').text());
  playerarray3 = $('option:selected').val();
  alert(playerarray3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Please select a footballer:</h2>

<div id="forms-col">
  <form name="" action="" id="formID">
    <label>Player 1:</label>
    <select player="name1">
      <option value='0'>-</option>
      <option value="{Team_Name:'Arsenal',Player_Ref:'1',Player_Name:'Mesut Ozil', Points:'5'}">Arsenal - Mesut Ozil - 5</option>
      <option value="{Team_Name:'Liverpool',Player_Ref:'2',Player_Name:'Daniel Sturridge', Points:'4'}">Liverpool - Daniel Sturridge - 4</option>
      <option value="{Team_Name:'Barcelona',Player_Ref:'3',Player_Name:'Lionel Messi', Points:'2'}">Barcelona - Lionel Messi - 2</option>
      <option value="{Team_Name:'PSG',Player_Ref:'4',Player_Name:'David Luis', Points:'4'}">PSG - David Luis - 7</option>
    </select>
    <BR>
    <label>Player 2:</label>
    <select player="name2">
      <option value='0'>-</option>
      <option value="{Team_Name:'Arsenal',Player_Ref:'1',Player_Name:'Mesut Ozil', Points:'5'}">Arsenal - Mesut Ozil - 5</option>
      <option value="{Team_Name:'Liverpool',Player_Ref:'2',Player_Name:'Daniel Sturridge', Points:'4'}">Liverpool - Daniel Sturridge - 4</option>
      <option value="{Team_Name:'Barcelona',Player_Ref:'3',Player_Name:'Lionel Messi', Points:'2'}">Barcelona - Lionel Messi - 2</option>
      <option value="{Team_Name:'PSG',Player_Ref:'4',Player_Name:'David Luis', Points:'4'}">PSG - David Luis - 7</option>
    </select>
    <BR>
    <label>Player 3:</label>
    <select player="name3">
      <option value='0'>-</option>
      <option value="{Team_Name:'Arsenal',Player_Ref:'1',Player_Name:'Mesut Ozil', Points:'5'}">Arsenal - Mesut Ozil - 5</option>
      <option value="{Team_Name:'Liverpool',Player_Ref:'2',Player_Name:'Daniel Sturridge', Points:'4'}">Liverpool - Daniel Sturridge - 4</option>
      <option value="{Team_Name:'Barcelona',Player_Ref:'3',Player_Name:'Lionel Messi', Points:'2'}">Barcelona - Lionel Messi - 2</option>
      <option value="{Team_Name:'PSG',Player_Ref:'4',Player_Name:'David Luis', Points:'4'}">PSG - David Luis - 7</option>
    </select>

  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Selected Goalscorers</h2>

  <table border="1">

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Form Select Info</td>
      <td>Team Name</td>
      <td>Player Name</td>
      <td>Player_Ref</td>
      <td>Points</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player 1:</td>
      <td><span id="Player_1"></span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player 2:</td>
      <td><span id="Player_2"></span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player 3:</td>
      <td><span id="Player_3"></span>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your values valid JSON like so:

```
<option value='{"Team_Name":"Arsenal","Player_Ref":"1","Player_Name":"Mesut Ozil", "Points":"5"}'>Arsenal - Mesut Ozil - 5</option>
```

...you can parse them with `JSON.parse` in your `change` handlers:

```
var data = JSON.parse($(this).val());
console.log(data.Team_Name); // Arsenal
```

Note that the `option`'s `value` attribute uses single quotes, and the property names and string values in it use double quotes (JSON requires double quotes). I've left `Player_Ref` and `Points` strings because you had them in quotes, but they look like numbers, in which case you can leave the `"` off them:

```
<option value='{"Team_Name":"Arsenal","Player_Ref":1,"Player_Name":"Mesut Ozil", "Points":5}'>Arsenal - Mesut Ozil - 5</option>
```